# Defining a virtual method inherited more than once

Tags: c++

I've been trying to find an answer to this question but I couldn't (I don't even know how to properly formulate this) so I decided to write my first post ever on StackOverflow =).

The context is the following:

I have this parent class:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(){};
    void foo(void)
    {
        //Do some common things
        bar();
        //Do some more common things
    };
protected:
    virtual void bar(void) = 0;
};
```

And I want to create an indefinite amount of derived Childs:

```
class Child1 : public Parent
{
public:
    Child1() : Parent(), child1Variable(0) {};
protected:
    virtual void bar(void) = 0;
private:
    uint32_t child1Variable;
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
    Child2() : Parent(), child2Variable(0) {};
protected:
    virtual void bar(void) = 0;
private:
    uint32_t child2Variable;
};

.
.
.

class ChildN : public Parent
{
public:
    ChildN() : Parent(), childNVariable(0) {};
protected:
    virtual void bar(void) = 0;
private:
    uint32_t childNVariable;
};
```

The reason being mainly not repeating the code in Parent's `foo()`

Then I would like to create my final instantiable classes as, for instance:

```
class ExampleFinal : public Child1, public Child3, public Child27
{
    //How to define Child1::bar(), Child3::bar() and Child27::bar() ??
private:
    void bar(void); //????
};
```

So the questions are:

1. How can I define the method for (abusing notation) `ExampleFinal::Child1::bar`, `ExampleFinal::Child3::bar`, ...
2. Am I so stuck on this that I'm overlooking a much simpler solution?

The final goal is being able to do something like:

```
ExampleFinal test;
test.Child1::foo(); //should end up on "ExampleFinal::Child1::bar"
test.Child3::foo(); //should end up on "ExampleFinal::Child3::bar"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that you don't need to repeat `virtual void bar(void) = 0;` in the derived classes?

Comment: If you need unlimited number of Child instances then you don't need unlimited number of Child class definitions, only one.

Comment: Why do you need different `Child` classes for ? Can't you just have a vector of `Child`ren ?

Comment: So... does each child really needs their own override of the member? I mean, you only seem to care about the most derived class anyway.

Comment: Child1 is not datamember of ExampleFinal so test.Child1 is incorrect

Comment: @Kapil `Child1` is part of `Child1::foo`, the qualified function name. This is fine.

Comment: @Kapil `test.Child1::foo` is perfectly valid syntax. It's parsed as `test . Child1::foo`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is going to be inheritance abuse; I have issues accepting that `ExampleFinal` "is a" `Child1` and a `Child2` and ....

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes. If I had an `ExampleFinal2 test2` that also derives from Child1, its `test2.Child1::bar()` would be different.

Comment: Since all your classes have same definition don't you think you need one child class and 27 child objects

Comment: Do you want that `ExampleFinal::foo()` calls `//Do some common things` once or number of children times ?

Comment: @Kapil They have the same definition to simplify te question. Each one could have it's own specific methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `ExampleFinal::bar()` (side-note: `bar(void)` is a C-ism which has no use in C++) will override all of the `bar`s you have declared at once. If you want to have different versions, you'll need to interpose another layer of classes:

```
struct GrandChild1 : Child1 {
    void bar() override { /*...*/ }
};

// And so on...

struct ExampleFinal : GrandChild1, GrandChild3, GrandChild27 {
    // Nothing needed here.
};
```

Then the behaviour you described will work. Be aware, though, that your inheritance graph means that an `ExampleFinal` has one `Parent` subobject *per `Child`*. This is not an issue in itself but might not model what you want -- maybe you need virtual inheritance here, but beware of the rabbit hole.

---

If you want to keep the overrides for all `ChildN::bar`s inside `ExampleFinal`, you can add tag-dispatching to discern them, at the cost of one more virtual call:

```
struct Parent {
    void foo() {
        bar();
    };

protected:
    template <class Child>
    struct tag { };
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

struct Child1 : Parent {
protected:
    virtual void bar(tag<Child1>) = 0;

    void bar() final override {
        return bar(tag<Child1>{});
    }

    int child1Var;
};

struct Child2 : Parent {
protected:
    virtual void bar(tag<Child2>) = 0;

    void bar() final override {
        return bar(tag<Child2>{});
    }

    int child2Var;
};

struct ExampleFinal : Child1, Child2 {
protected:
    using Parent::tag;

    void bar(tag<Child1>) final override {
        std::cout << "Child1::bar\n";
    }

    void bar(tag<Child2>) final override {
        std::cout << "Child2::bar\n";
    }
};
```

Note that the `bar()` to `bar(tag<ChildN>)` bridge can easily be hidden behind a macro. If you want to avoid the cost of the second virtual call, a CRTP can also be applied here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I supposed that adding more layers would be doable, but it starts to get messy. 
I know that the final object will contain a `Parent` object per child, but I think this is necessary to being able to override bar on each child. My plan was to make `Parent` inherit virtually from a base class containing a couple of common variables to every child.

Comment: @Kai I have added another spin on my solution.